# Create a formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I placed my field `ParentDied` from table `tblSIF` onto my page report. If the report loads, the condition should be:

```
 IF ParentDied = 0 THEN 'None' ELSE 'Deceased'
```

I searched on the Internet and found this:

```
`IF {@Ship Days} = 0 THEN "Same Day" ELSE {@Ship Days}`
```

Where did `@Ship` come from? Is that a parameter? All I know is that the field is named by CR as `tblSIF.ParentDied`. How can I make a formula of my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create and use a formula on your report follow these steps:

1. Right Click `Formula Fields` and select `New...`

   [image]
2. Input a name for your formula

   [image]
3. In the `Formula Workshop` add in your expression

   [image]

   Based on your example this will be something like:

   ```
   If {tblSIF.ParentDied} = 0 Then "None" Else "Deceased"
   ```
4. Drag the report onto the report to display

   Design:

   [image]

   Preview:

   [image]

Comment: The other condition is if the value also was 1, how can I make the color background of a field into black?

Comment: Is it possible, because I read some forum that, it can but not in the box object.

Comment: Yes you can. To do this right click the field and select `Format Field`. On the `Border` tab check the checkbox `Background`. Click the button that looks like `X-2` and input your formula in there. Would be something like  `If {tblSIF.ParentDied} = 1 Then crBlack`

Comment: You rock it sir. I got it. Thank you very much. :))

Comment: @JeraldVicente no problem.